# A syntax error has occurred on UPDATE command

Tags: sql, database, informix

Is this the correct syntax for an Informix UPDATE?

```
UPDATE da1010
SET d1.da1_prcven = s9.b9_cm1, d1.datvig = s9.b9_data
FROM da1010 d1
INNER JOIN sb1010 s1
    ON (d1.da1_codpro = s1.b1_cod AND s1.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*')
INNER JOIN sb9010 S9
    ON (s9.b9_filial = '0101' AND s9.b9_cm1 <> 0 AND d1.da1_codpro = s9.b9_cod AND d1.da1_datvig < s9.b9_data AND s1.b1_locpad = s9.b9_local AND s9.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*')
WHERE d1.da1_codtab = '009'
    AND d1.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
    AND s9.b9_data = (SELECT MAX(b9_data) FROM SB9010)
```

when I give the command to execute a query the editor returns a syntax error (-201: A syntax error has occurred).

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What would be the error message? Just sayin'

Comment: Informix syntax doesn't include a `FROM` clause (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm).  Your intention is rather unclear.

Comment: The message just explains about a syntax error, don't displays more informations. Gordon, the query must update all entries according to the conditions in the where block. I will revise the code again according to the IBM documentation.Thank you all, I'll keep trying.

Comment: I think the general form you would need to use would be something like this
update table
set (col1, col2) = (select newcol1, newcol2 from ...)
Just not sure if your where clause would only be on the select or if you only wanted to update some of the rows in the original table.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, I need to update all the rows of table 'da1' with values and dates that are in another table 'sb9', but for this I need to validate some information in a third table 'sb1'.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE ([MCVE]), which in the context of an SQL question means you need to provide outline schemas for the table you use, and sample data with a few rows in each table, and the desired result from the sample data.  Where you've got a syntax error, you can't provide the actual data you're getting, but it is worth including the exact error message, even when it is the bane of your life (and mine) — the anodyne, non-informative -210: A syntax error has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after spending a lot of work with the query and attentation studying the documentation of informix, I came to the solution of the problem, I share here with you to finalize the topic.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_update_table()
DEFINE x_cod    varchar(15) ;    --declaration local variable
DEFINE x_date   varchar(8)  ;
DEFINE x_vlr    float       ;

FOREACH    --selects rows according to query
SELECT b9_cod, b9_data, b9_cm1 
INTO x_cod, x_date, x_vlr
FROM SB9010
INNER JOIN DA1010 ON (b9_cod = da1_codpro AND da1_datvig < b9_data)
INNER JOIN SB1010 ON (b9_cod = b1_cod AND b9_local = b1_locpad)
WHERE b9_cm1 <> '0'
AND SB9010.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*'
AND b9_data = (SELECT MAX(b9_data) FROM SB9010)

UPDATE DA1010    --update fields with variables values
SET da1_prcven = x_vlr, da1_datvig = x_date   
AND da1_codpro = x_cod
AND da1_datvig < x_date 
AND d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*';
END FOREACH;
END PROCEDURE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you to update the table da1010 with informations requested, but in that line:

SET d1.da1_prcven = s9.b9_cm1, d1.datvig = s9.b9_data

Do you update the informations of table D1 and NOT of table da1010 as sould it. The correct update is below:

```
UPDATE da1010
SET da1010.da1_prcven = s9.b9_cm1, da1010.datvig = s9.b9_data
FROM da1010 d1
INNER JOIN sb1010 s1
    ON (d1.da1_codpro = s1.b1_cod AND s1.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*')
INNER JOIN sb9010 S9
    ON (s9.b9_filial = '0101' AND s9.b9_cm1 <> 0 AND d1.da1_codpro = s9.b9_cod AND d1.da1_datvig < s9.b9_data AND s1.b1_locpad = s9.b9_local AND s9.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*')
WHERE d1.da1_codtab = '009'
    AND d1.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*' 
    AND s9.b9_data = (SELECT MAX(b9_data) FROM SB9010)
```

**PS: You can't use alias in update, only after FROM.**

Comment: I hope to be help you.

Comment: This won't help; Informix doesn't recognize this syntax with a FROM clause — see the [UPDATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) statement in the Informix SQL Syntax Manual.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use MERGE:

```
 MERGE INTO dept d
     USING dept_online o
     ON (d.deptno = o.deptno)
     WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET d.dname = o.dname, d.loc = o.loc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an [UPDATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) statement with syntax that matches what Informix supports.

It will have the general form of:

```
UPDATE target
   SET (col1, …, colN) = ((SELECT val1, …, valN FROM WhereEver …))
 WHERE …
```

The double-parentheses on the RHS of the SET clause are deliberate and necessary.  The WHERE clause in the main UPDATE must ensure that only rows that will be updated with a value from the SELECT statement are selected.  If you don't, the rows without a matching entry will have `col1, …, colN` set to NULL, which is rarely what is wanted.

Trying to apply this to your query, maybe something along the lines of this:

```
UPDATE da1010 AS d1
   SET (da1_prcven, datvig) = ((SELECT s9.b9_cm1, s9.b9_data
                                  FROM sb1010 s1
                                  JOIN sb9010 S9 ON (s9.b9_filial  =  '0101' AND
                                                     s9.b9_cm1     <> 0 AND
                                                     s9.b9_cod     =  s1.b1_cod AND
                                                     s9.b9_local   =  s1.b1_locpad AND
                                                     s9.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*')
                                 WHERE d1.da1_codtab = '009'
                                   AND d1.da1_datvig < s9.b9_data
                                   AND d1.da1_codpro = s1.b1_cod
                                   AND d1.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*'
                                   AND s1.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*'
                                   AND s9.b9_data = (SELECT MAX(b9_data) FROM sb9010)
                              ))
 WHERE d1.da1_codtab = '009'
   AND d1.d_e_l_e_t_ <> '*';
```

This is not correct, but it is sufficiently near to correct that it runs and updates the target table, `d1010`.

Sample SQL used for testing.  Note that the SQL in the question refers to both `datvig` and `da1_datvig` in the `da1010` table.  I think `datvig` is probably a typo, but since the outline schema wasn't provided, it is hard to be sure.

```
CREATE TABLE da1010
(
    da1_prcven  INTEGER,
    datvig      INTEGER,    -- Original references both datvig and da1_datvig
    da1_datvig  INTEGER,    -- Original references both datvig and da1_datvig
    da1_codpro  INTEGER,
    da1_codtab  CHAR(3),
    d_e_l_e_t_  CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE sb1010
(
    b1_cod      INTEGER,
    b1_locpad   INTEGER,
    d_e_l_e_t_  CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE sb9010
(
    b9_cm1      INTEGER,
    b9_data     INTEGER,
    b9_cod      INTEGER,
    b9_local    INTEGER,
    b9_filial   CHAR(4),
    d_e_l_e_t_  CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO da1010 VALUES(100, 1000, 100, 100, '009', 'N');
INSERT INTO da1010 VALUES(102, 1000, 101, 102, '009', 'N');
INSERT INTO da1010 VALUES(102, 1000, 101, 102, '009', '*');

INSERT INTO sb1010 VALUES(100, 20, 'N');
INSERT INTO sb1010 VALUES(100, 30, '*');
INSERT INTO sb1010 VALUES(101, 99, 'N');
INSERT INTO sb1010 VALUES(102, 40, 'N');
INSERT INTO sb1010 VALUES(102, 50, '*');

INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2345, 3456, 100, 20, '0101', 'N');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2344, 3466, 102, 40, '0101', 'N');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2343, 3476, 100, 20, '0101', 'N');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2342, 3486, 100, 20, '0101', 'N');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2341, 3496, 101, 40, '0101', 'N');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2345, 3456, 100, 20, '0101', '*');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2344, 3466, 102, 40, '0101', '*');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2343, 3476, 100, 20, '0101', '*');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2342, 3486, 100, 20, '0101', '*');
INSERT INTO sb9010 VALUES(2341, 3496, 101, 40, '0101', '*');
```

Before:

```
SELECT * FROM da1010;
100|1000|100|100|009|N
102|1000|101|102|009|N
102|1000|101|102|009|*
```

After:

```
SELECT * FROM da1010;
||100|100|009|N
||101|102|009|N
102|1000|101|102|009|*
```

As you can see, the `da1_prcven` and `datvig` columns on two rows were nullified.  That shows a couple of things:

1. I didn't manage to generate data that satisfies the update conditions.
2. I didn't get the WHERE clause in the main UPDATE sufficiently selective.  It quite likely needs a significant chunk of the SELECT statement from the SET clause in the main WHERE clause.

However, I can't make head or tail of exactly what the UPDATE is supposed to do, so I'm unwilling to spend more time on second-guessing what's meant to be going on.

Comment: thanks for all who answered, but I still have not found the satisfactory solution to my problem, I will conitnuar in the "battle", and as soon as I find the solution I bring it to you